# Order by the name a list in Vue.js while clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js

I'm playing around with Vue.js and I am struggling to figure out how to sort a list while I am clicking a button.

Actually, I did succeed to sort the list using orderedBeers method; when I click the button I can see the ordered list in the inspector but I can't change the data in HTML.

Every recommendation is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div class=" main-conte" >
   
<transition-group name="fade" tag="div" id="container"  class=" row "  >
      <figure v-for="(value,index) in  toBeShown" id="page-wrap" :key="index" class="beer-container col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-2"   >
         <a  >
    <img @click="goTodetail(value.id)" class="logo lazy img-responsive loaded" v-bind:src="getMissingImg(index)"/>
          <figcaption>
            <div class="beer-title">{{value.name}}</div>
            <div class="beer-availability"> {{value.tagline}}</div>
            <div class="learn-more">
              <h4 class="beer-info-title">Format</h4>
              <span class="serving-icons"></span>
              <div class="serving">
             <i v-if="value.abv >= 0 && value.abv <=6 " class="fas fa-wine-glass-alt"></i> 
             <i v-if="value.abv >= 6 && value.abv <=7" class="fas fa-glass-cheers"></i>
             <i v-if="value.abv >= 7 && value.abv <=100" class="fas fa-wine-bottle"></i>
             <span class="measure">{{value.abv}}</span>%
 </div>
 </div>
   </figcaption>
      </a>
     </figure>
     </transition-group>
<div class=prev-next>
  <button @click="orderedBeers">Click Me!</button>

<button class="prev" @click="prevPage" :disabled="currentPage==1">
<i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></button>
      <button class="next"  @click="nextPage" :disabled="currentPage == totalPages">
<i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>     </button>
</div>
</div>
       <div>
       </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mdbView, mdbMask } from "mdbvue";
import FadeTransition from "./fade-transition.vue";



export default {
  name: "home",
  components: {
    mdbView,
    mdbMask,
    FadeTransition
  },

  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
      currentPage: 1,

 };
  },
  computed: {
    //show more less products
   toBeShown() {
     return this.items.slice(0, this.currentPage * 5);
    },
    totalPages() {
      return Math.ceil( this.items.length / 4);
    },
 
 
   
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchData();
    
  },
  


  methods: {
    fetchData: function() {
      const myRequest = new Request("https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers");

      fetch(myRequest)
        .then(response => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          this.items = data;

          console.log(this.items);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
    getMissingImg(index) {
      return this.images[index];
    },

    nextPage(){
      if(this.currentPage <  this.totalPages) this.currentPage++;
      // this.scrollToEnd();
    },
    prevPage(){
      this.currentPage = this.currentPage - 1 || 1;
      // this.scrollToEnd();
    },
      goTodetail(prodId) {
    let proId=prodId
    this.$router.push({name:'blog',params:{Pid:proId}})
    
      },

         orderedBeers: function () {
    console.log(_.orderBy(this.toBeShown, 'name', 'asc'));

    return _.orderBy(this.toBeShown, 'name', 'asc');

  },
  }
};
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source of data is the computed property `toBeShown`. If you want your data to be presented sorted `toBeShown` must return that.

In `orderedBeers` you are sorting the items `returned` by `toBeShown` when you should be changing `toBeShown` to use the sorted data itself.

Change `orderedBeers` to update `data.items` to reflect the new ordering:

```
orderedBeers: function () {
  this.data.items = _.orderBy(this.data.items, 'name', 'asc')
}
```

This will sort the entire item list and not only the current displayed page.

Or

Use a sorting flag and move the sorting login inside `toBeShown`

```
data() {
 return {
  items: [],
  currentPage: 1,
  sorted: false
 }
}
...
orderedBeers: function () {
  this.sorted = true
}
...
toBeShown() {
    return this.sorted ? _.orderBy(this.data.items, 'name', 'asc').slice( 0, this.currentPage) : this.items.slice(0, this.currentPage * 5);
}
```

This will also sorts all of the items, but can change the code a bit to only sort the current displayed page

```
toBeShown() {
    let items = this.items.slice(0, this.currentPage * 5)
    return this.sorted ? _.orderBy(items, 'name', 'asc') : items
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You just need to use another computed property that sorts the list and use that in your `v-for`.

Modify the template to:

```
<figure v-for="(value,index) in toBeShownOrdered" id="page-wrap" :key="index" >

<button @click="orderByName = !orderByName">Click Me!</button>
```

And the component to:

```
// Add in data:
orderByName: false,

// Add in computed
toBeShownOrdered() {
  return this.orderByName ? _.orderBy(this.toBeShown, 'name', 'asc') : this.toBeShown;
}
```

See also here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Displaying-Filtered-Sorted-Results